# Best way to design a class in python

Tags: python, oop, class, coding-style

So, this is more like a philosophical question for someone who is trying to understand classes.

Most of the time, how I use classes are actually a very bad way to use them. I think of a lot of functions and after a time just indent the code and makes it a class, replacing stuff with self.variable if a variable is repeated a lot. (I know it's bad practise)
But anyways... What I am asking is:

```
 class FooBar:
       def __init__(self,foo,bar):
           self._foo = foo
           self._bar = bar
           self.ans = self.__execute()

       def __execute(self):
            return something(self._foo, self._bar)
```

Now there are many ways to do this:

```
   class FooBar:
         def __init__(self,foo):
           self._foo = foo


       def execute(self,bar):
            return something(self._foo, bar)
```

Can you suggest which one is bad and which one is worse?

Or suggest any other ways to do this.

This is just a toy example of course. I mean, there is no need to have a class here if there is only one function.. but let's say in __execute something() calls a whole set of other methods?

Thanks

Comment: Why a `__execute` and not a `__call__` ? To make a class instance callable like a function ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

That said, http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Programming-Python-Michael-Goldwasser/dp/0136150314/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1347463941&sr=8-5&keywords=object+oriented+design+in+python

Comment: "What's the best way to make a class?" is not really a simply answered question.  "What's the best way to make a class given that you're trying to solve problem X?" is a much better question per the FAQ link that I posted.  If you don't want to buy a book, at least read this: http://codingarchitect.wordpress.com/2006/09/27/four-tenets-of-oop/

Comment: @Pierre GM - for that matter, why `__execute` and not `post_to_db`?

Comment: @BenBurns : why not indeed ? You're quite right in pointing that different goals will need different means and different implementations. It's just a matter of being as specific about your problem as possible...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If each `FooBar` is responsible for `bar` then the first is correct. If `bar` is only needed for `execute()` but not `FooBar`'s problem otherwise, the second is correct.

Comment: Shouldnt you declare all input variables in _init_ so you can easily see the interface of the object and program according to it. The second example looks like leakage to me because imagine many functions within the class and one of them has a variable that is not declared in _init_ and is needed for the function. It is like buried/hidden from the programmer's sight

Answer (score 5):

**In a single phrase, the formal term you want to worry about here is *Separation of Concerns***.

In response to your specific example, which of the two examples you choose depends on the concerns solved by `FooBar` and `bar`.  If `bar` is in the same problem domain as `FooBar` or if it otherwise makes sense for `FooBar` to store a reference to `bar`, then the second example is correct.  For instance, if `FooBar` has multiple methods that accept a `bar` and if you always pass the same instance of `bar` to each of a particular `FooBar` instance's `bar`-related methods, then the prior example is correct.  Otherwise, the latter is more correct.

Ideally, each class you create should model exactly one major concern of your program.  This can get a bit tricky, because you have to decide the granularity of "major concern" for yourself.  Look to your dependency tree to determine if you're doing this correctly.  It should be relatively easy to pull each individual class out of your program and test it in isolation from all other classes.  If this is very difficult, you haven't split your concerns correctly.  More formally, good separation of concerns is accomplished by designing classes which are [**cohesive** and **loosely coupled**](http://jasoncoffin.com/2011/03/10/cohesion-and-coupling-principles-of-orthogonal-object-orientated-programming/).

While this isn't useful for the example you posted, one simple pattern that helps accomplish this on a broader scale is Inversion of Control (IoC, sometimes called Dependency Injection).  Under IoC, classes are written such that they aren't aware of their dependencies directly, only the interfaces (protocols in Python-speak) which their dependencies implement.  Then at run time, typically during application initialization, instances of major classes are created by factories, and they are assigned references to their actual dependencies.  See [this article](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DependencyInjectionPattern) (with [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413268/)) for an explanation of how this can be accomplished in Python.

Finally, learn [the four tenets of object-oriented programming](http://codingarchitect.wordpress.com/2006/09/27/four-tenets-of-oop/).